# How to Draw Arc In windows phone 7 in canvas in Runtime?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

The Challenge is that i have to make a canvas object in runtime for windows phone 7. And then Add a arc on it , with a startpoint and one end Point . i have tried this code

```
    PathGeometry pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
    PathFigure figure = new PathFigure();
    figure.StartPoint = new Point(150, 200);
    figure.Segments.Add(
    new ArcSegment(
    new Point(300, 200),
    new Size(700, 100),
    90,
    false,
    SweepDirection.Clockwise,
    true
    )
    );
    pathGeometry.Figures.Add(figure);
    Path path = new Path();
    path.Data = pathGeometry;
    path.Fill = Brushes.Pink;
    path.Stroke = Brushes.Green;
```

now I have to add this arc on canvas but it does not take arguments . is there any other way to do it . I am stuck with it .

Comment: Did you tried _anything_ so far?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't take arguments" ? Did you try myCanvas.Children.Add(path) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I guess Arc means this type of figure, [image]

To draw this arc, I had used this code , which works fine for me and quite similar to your code also, hope it helps you ..

```
 PathFigure pthFigure1 = new PathFigure();
    pthFigure1.StartPoint = new Point(50, 60);// starting cordinates of arcs
    ArcSegment arcSeg1 = new ArcSegment();
    arcSeg1.Point = new Point(100, 82);   // ending cordinates of arcs
    arcSeg1.Size = new Size(10, 10);

    arcSeg1.IsLargeArc = false;
    arcSeg1.SweepDirection = SweepDirection.Clockwise;
    arcSeg1.RotationAngle = 90;
    PathSegmentCollection myPathSegmentCollection1 = new PathSegmentCollection();
    myPathSegmentCollection1.Add(arcSeg1);
    pthFigure1.Segments = myPathSegmentCollection1;
    PathFigureCollection pthFigureCollection1 = new PathFigureCollection();
    pthFigureCollection1.Add(pthFigure1);
    PathGeometry pthGeometry1 = new PathGeometry();
    pthGeometry1.Figures = pthFigureCollection1;
    System.Windows.Shapes.Path arcPath1 = new System.Windows.Shapes.Path();
    arcPath1.Data = pthGeometry1;
    arcPath1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 23, 0));
    this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(arcPath1);
```